# Shape from Pushpins, actions on them

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am very curious, I have for example a app to localize our property, our first, second house, favorite park and we can add pushpin**s** to corners of this property in a way to form a shape(triangle, square, polygon etc), not a line or point. 
How to create this shape, there is a method to calculate the surface area? Change a background for example to color yellow between these pushpins ? 
When we created a shape we can chose from the listbox or map to delete this shape or go to there using GPS, i wrote something like that in [Simulate my current position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207327/simulate-my-current-position)

I think its a interesting app but i need your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the geocoordinates of each pushpin and using maths? I guess you could assume the flatness of the Earth over a small area (like a house) but over larger you'll need to account for curvature.

As for colouring the shapes in, I don't think there's a way to do this using the Map control.